# Can an Action be used for an ability that specifies it requires a Bonus Action?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions

For instance, Mood Druids can spend a Bonus Action to spend a spellslot and heal [D8*S]hp while in wild shape. If the druid wants to use a feature that normally requires a bonus action (such as sustaining/retriggering the effect of a spell), and also use this feature in the same turn, can the druid spend his action and bonus action to do both bonus-action abilities?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use a spell with a casting time of "Bonus Action" as my action?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55899/can-i-use-a-spell-with-a-casting-time-of-bonus-action-as-my-action) Note that it would probably more appropriately be a dupe of [Can I use my action to do something that requires a bonus action?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78821/can-i-use-my-action-to-do-something-that-requires-a-bonus-action?lq=1) but that question is closed as a dupe of the previously link question as well.

Comment: Huh, I searched for Bonus Action questions to check if this had been asked, but I must have missed that second one