# Spell Casting Time messed with by Wild Magic?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, sorcerer, wild-magic

The *Wild Magic* result on 27-28 is

> For the next minute, all your spells with a casting time of 1 action have a casting time of 1 bonus action.

Does this mean that you can **only** cast spells (other than *reaction* spells) as a bonus action, and that you can't use your action to cast one normally?

I am specifically asking whether or not your spells with a casting time of 1 action can still be cast with an action, or whether the effect **absolutely** replaces the casting time rather than expanding your options.

Comment: Duplicate (?): [Can I use a spell with a casting time of bonus action as my action](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55899/can-i-use-a-spell-with-a-casting-time-of-bonus-action-as-my-action)

Comment: @Thyzer That is suspiciously similar, I will admit. But I am more asking about the verbiage of the effect, since I already knew the other part that the other question asks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, this means those spells no longer have a casting of time of one Action, as it's been changed to Bonus Action. [You don't have a choice of which to use](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55899/can-i-use-a-spell-with-a-casting-time-of-bonus-action-as-my-action), since they can no longer be cast using your Action.

Comment: Just to add to this, it does indeed expand your options, you can activate a magic item as your action and still cast something like fireball or other full cast spell. To be perfectly honest if you have the right gear this could be scary.