# Are actions and bonus actions interchangeable?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, action-economy, bonus-action

While I know you can't cast 2 spells of first level or higher in a turn, and actions can't just be used as bonus actions, is the reverse true?

Say there's a barbarian cleric that rages as a bonus action: can they use healing word as an action, when it normally takes a bonus action? Can bonus actions be used as actions in the case of using a bonus for something else such as rage?

Comment: [Related] [Can I use a spell with a casting time of "Bonus Action" as my action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55899)

Answer (score 27):

This has been officially answered in the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=11):

> **Q: Can a bonus action be used as an action or vice versa? For example, can a bard use a bonus action to grant a Bardic Inspiration die and an action to cast *healing word*?**
>
> A: No. Actions and bonus actions aren't interchangeable. In the example, the bard could use Bardic Inspiration or *healing word* on a turn, but not both.

Comment: That seems so counter-intuitive!

Comment: I guess you could look at it as "casting a spell *quickly* takes up a certain amount of arcane energy. Within the space of 6 seconds, you can only access a small amount more."

Answer (score 3):

RAW, no; they are separate categories.  My own inclination is that bonus actions are specifically quicker than full actions, and I will almost always allow a character to use his full action to perform a bonus action.  It doesn't break the game.