# How to get more Bonus Actions?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions

Other than having the Haste spell cast on you and using the action provided to use something that requires a bonus action are there any other ways to gain additional bonus actions in 5e?

Comment: Of note: You cannot exchange an Action for a Bonus Action: [Are actions and bonus actions interchangeable?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111389/are-actions-and-bonus-actions-interchangeable)

Comment: Gain more than one bonus action per round, or more than one per turn? There are ways to gain extra turns per round, and therefore extra bonus actions per round, as a couple answers mention (and there's at least one not mentioned; the Samurai Fighter's Strength before Death ability) but additional bonus actions per turn is a different question.

Answer (score 54):

No, there are no ways to gain an additional bonus action. Note that I didn't say no *others* - the *Haste* spell doesn't give you one either.

> Until the spell ends, the target [...] gains an additional action on each
>   of its turns. That action can be used only to take the
>   Attack (one weapon attack only), Dash, Disengage, Hide,
>   or Use an Object action.

This isn't an additional bonus action, it's an additional action.

It's hard to prove a negative, but as of 22/01/2018, there are no officially published methods (or Unearthed Arcana) of gaining additional bonus actions.

Comment: Would you count time stop as a bonus action (from the next answer down). It almost strikes me more as PREVENTING actions from others, and you just going as normal for 1d4+1 turns.

Comment: Might be worth quoting the actual rule (PHB p189: "You can only take one bonus action on your turn, so you must choose which bonus action to use when you have more than one available").

Answer (score 31):

Only by a few high-level abilities which give you *entire new turns* during a round.

9th level spell [Time Stop](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/time-stop):

> You briefly stop the flow of time for everyone but yourself. No time passes for other creatures, while you take 1d4 + 1 turns in a row, during which you can use actions and move as normal.

... which includes bonus actions.

The Rogue class [Thief archetype](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/rogue#Thief) has a 17th level ability called **Thief's Reflexes**, which also similarly gives an additional bonus action as part of giving you a whole additional turn:

> You can take two turns during the first round of any combat. You take your first turn at your normal initiative and your second turn at your initiative minus 10.

Short of these, no. Limiting bonus actions to just the one appears to be a fundamental design point. Time Stop takes a highest-tier spell, and even then, the extra actions are quite limited (the spell ends if your actions affect other creatures!). And the Thief ability requires a high character level (the same level that casters are getting 9th level spells, in fact.) This strongly indicates that limiting actions per turn *in general* is a big concern to 5E.

Comment: As well it should be - probably the major reasons for the 3.0 -> 3.5 version bump was various fixes to D&D's action economy, like adding the concept of swift actions and nerfing the Haste spell.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the previously mentioned "Time Stop" and "Thief's Reflexes" abilities, "Xanathar's Guide to Everything" has the Samurai subclass for Fighters that get a feature called "Strength Before Death" at level 18- it gives another turn interrupting the current turn as a reaction when the Samurai would drop to 0 hit points. If the Samurai dropped to 0 hit points during their own turn, they would be able to use a Bonus Action on their initial turn and during this new turn before any other creature has a turn.

Additionally, since you've mentioned Haste in your initial question, I think it's worth noting that all Fighters can use "Action Surge" at level 2 for an additional action on their turn, and "Unearthed Arcana: The Faithful" introduced the Seeker Patron for Warlocks which have the "Astral Refuge" ability at level 6 that allows two additional limited actions on their turn; neither of these options would allow for an extra bonus action however.

Answer (score 2):

There is one way (and only one, AFAIK) to get two bonus actions in a round, and that is the 17th level Rogue's power of "Thief's Reflexes". that gives him two full turns in the first round of any combat.

Comment: It doesn't give you two bonus actions in a turn, though. It gives you *two turns*, each with their own action, bonus action and movement.

Comment: Same as Time Stop, basically.

Comment: Edited to note that it allows two bonus actions in a round, not turn.  You're right, they are separate turns, although the fact that it allows two turns in a round amounts to pretty much the same thing.