# Can I use Hex (Spell) and Hexblade's Curse in 1 round

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, hexblade

Is it possible to use both **Hex** (Spell) and **Hexblade's Curse** (Hex Blade ability) in 1 round of combat? These are both bonus actions. I expect if its possible you would use up your *bonus* and *attack* action for the round, leaving *movement* and *reaction*.

I do apologise if this is duplicated, I looked high and low for previous discussion on this.

Comment: I've edited your post to remove the second question. We have a One Question per Post policy. Feel free to ask the other question in a separate question.

Comment: Heavily related: [Can I use a spell with a casting time of “Bonus Action” as my action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55899/41726)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No, you only get one bonus action per turn

The only way to use both *Hex* and *Hexblade's Curse* at the same time is if you had cast one on a previous turn.

Answer (score 8):

## Generally, no

You only get one bonus action per turn and you cannot use your action to do something that takes a bonus action. There are no spells, feats, or class features that can bypass this restriction.

## With *find familiar* and a *ring of spell storing*, probably

If you have the *find familiar* spell (PHB, p. 240) and a *ring of spell storing* (DMG, p. 192), [your familiar can attune to and use the ring](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/107333/47185). You just need to cast the *hex* spell into the ring before combat, and then the familiar can cast it for you in the same round that you use Hexblade's Curse. As written, the familiar "rolls its own initiative and acts on its own turn", but most DMs I have played with prefer to let it act on your turn.

This is somewhat up to DM discretion, as it isn't clear if an owl or lizard can wear a ring (but an octopus probably can). If this becomes a problem, ask your DM if any of the special familiars - imp, pseudodragon, quasit, or sprite - granted by Pact of the Chain (PHB, p. 107) would work.

## As a Thief Rogue 17 / Hexblade 1, yes

> ### Thief's Reflexes
>
> When you reach 17th level, you have become adept at laying ambushes and quickly escaping danger. **You can take two *turns* during the first *round* of any combat.** You take your first turn at your normal initiative and your second turn at your initiative minus 10. You can't use this feature when you are surprised.
>
> *PHB, p. 97, emphasis mine*

This 17th-level Thief Rogue ability will allow you to use two bonus actions in the same *round* (though not in the same *turn*).

Comment: That was very insightful, actually helps with other ideas as well.
Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

### You cannot use your action to perform a bonus action

So, no. AFAIK while there are ways to get additional actions (e.g. Fighter's Action Surge) there is nothing that will give you additional bonus actions.