# If you cast a cantrip as a bonus action, can you also cast a cantrip as your action?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions, spellcasting, cantrips

The rule in the PHB is fairly clear on casting a cantrip and a spell: if the spell is a bonus action, you may cast a cantrip as an action.

My question concerns the two bonus-action cantrips, *magic stone* and *shillelagh*. Can one of these spells be cast as a bonus action and then another cantrip, like *fire bolt*, be cast as an action?

Comment: Related: [Which uses of Bonus-Action spellcasting are legal?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133767/which-uses-of-bonus-action-spellcasting-are-legal) (your question's covered as part of that one)

Comment: Related: [Can I use a spell with a casting time of “Bonus Action” as my action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55899/can-i-use-a-spell-with-a-casting-time-of-bonus-action-as-my-action)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Casting bonus-action spells (including cantrips) prevents you from casting action spells of 1st level or higher, not cantrips

Specifically, what the rule (PHB 202; Casting Time > Bonus Action) says is that when you have cast any spell (including cantrips) using your bonus action, you are limited to casting a cantrip using your action (i.e. not a spell of 1st level or higher).

Thus, you can cast cantrips with both your action and bonus action on the same turn.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was not the first one i saw, but it actually answered a questione I thought of a day later, that is if a leveled spell could be cast as an action after casting a bonus action cantrip

Answer (score 22):

### You can cast the two cantrips

Cantrips are spells. Therefore, unless specified otherwise, they follow all the rules that apply to spells in general. The status of cantrips as spells is often forgotten because many rules specifically refer to "spells of 1st level or higher", but unless so excluded they do count as spells. This is specified in the Basic rules (available for free on [DnD Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#SpellLevel)):

> #### Spell level
>
> Every spell has a level from 0 to 9. A spell's level is a general indicator of how powerful it is, with the lowly (but still impressive) magic missile at 1st level and the earth-shaking wish at 9th. Cantrips -- simple but powerful spells that characters can cast almost by rote -- are level 0.  ...
>
> ...
>
> #### Cantrips
>
> A cantrip is a spell that can be cast at will, without using a spell slot and without being prepared in advance.

So the normal rule applies: if you cast any spell – cantrip or not – as a Bonus Action, you can cast another spell on the same turn only if it's a cantrip with a casting time of one Action. Fire bolt is such a cantrip, so casting it to follow after a Bonus Action spell, cantrip or otherwise, is legal.

Answer (score 6):

### Yes.

This rule appears in Chapter 9: Spellcasting of the Basic Rules (and PHB). In the [Casting Time section](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingTime), it states:

> #### Bonus Action
>
> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn. **You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.**

In the same chapter, under [Cantrips](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Cantrips), the rules define a cantrip as:

> **a spell that can be cast at will**, without using a spell slot and without being prepared in advance.

(Emphasis mine in both excerpts.)

When the rules specifically exclude cantrips, they use the phrase “spells of 1st level and higher” (for example in the Spellcasting class features granted to many classes). The term “spell” on its own includes both cantrips and higher level spells.

Therefore **yes**: if you use your Bonus Action to cast any spell with a casting time of 1 Bonus Action, including the cantrips *magic stone* and *shillelagh*, you can then use your Action in the same turn to cast a cantrip with a casting time of 1 Action.

Comment: Not to be cross, but one could argue that the rules actually states that you can't cast two bonus action cantrips as there is no explicity to whether you can cast a bonus action cantrip as a action instead. This is further supported by: "You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.". However I can hardly imagine this is on purpose due to balancing issues, maybe it's just a lack of explicity in the RAW.

Comment: @KasperThystrupKarstensen oh, no question there - you only get one bonus action per turn, and you can’t substitute a bonus action for an action. But the question isn’t asking that, it’s asking if the bonus action spell is a cantrip, can you still cast another cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.

Comment: *@Guybrush - Note that I posted my previous comment prematurely, so you did not get the entirety of the comment - sorry about that!* I think we are misinterpreting each other. It seems that magic stone and shillelagh are both bonus action cantrips.

Comment: @KasperThystrupKarstensen oh - yes. That’s explicitly stated in both the question and my answer.

Comment: @KasperThystrupKarstensen The wording of the OP is somewhat misleading, perhaps, but it doesn't concern casting both of them, but one of those followed by a cantrip with a casting time of Action.

Comment: I think we are on the same page; Casting a cantrip as a bonus action, and then casting another bonus action cantrip as an action all in one turn, is it allowed. But I'm curious as to whether there are actually any rule statements that specifically allows for casting a bonus action cantrip -> with an action! It makes sense to allow it, but is it actually specified in RAW? This would be a relevant point, to provide a precise answer.

Comment: @KasperThystrupKarstensen, no the question here is about casting a cantrip as a bonus action, and then casting a _non-bonus-action_ cantrip. This question may help you answer yours: [Can I use a spell with a casting time of “Bonus Action” as my action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55899/can-i-use-a-spell-with-a-casting-time-of-bonus-action-as-my-action)

Comment: Ahh thank you for taking the time to clarify, now I finally understand! -> I didn't register the "another cantrip, like firebolt" part of the question, and instead interpreted it as casting Magic stone and Shillelagh in the same turn..